# Using complex vectors in GSL C++

Tags: c++, gsl

I'm trying to use the GSL library to process complex values.
In the following code, I try to create a complex vector, fill it with the same value, and then read it.

```
int N = 5;
gsl_vector_complex * Data = gsl_vector_complex_alloc(N);
gsl_complex temp = gsl_complex_rect(1,2);

gsl_vector_complex_set_all(Data,temp);

for(int i =0;i<N;i++)
{
cout << GSL_REAL(gsl_vector_complex_get(Data,i)) << "  " << GSL_IMAG(gsl_vector_complex_get(Data,i)) << endl;
}

gsl_vector_complex_free(Data);
```

But the output I've got is wrong :

[image]

I tried to follow the evolution of the memory with the debugger, and it looks like when i reaches 3, I lose all the elements from Data and temp :

[image]

[image]

Here are my includes :

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
> #include <gsl/gsl_complex.h>
> #include <gsl/gsl_complex_math.h>
> ```

Comment: What did you expect as result?

Comment: I expected 1 as real part and 2 as imaginary part for all of my vector elements, since I used the set all method with cartesian values 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your compilation workflow. In fact, I have tried to reproduce your problem by compiling

```
g++ complex.cpp -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

with the following file complex.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex_math.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int N = 5;
    gsl_vector_complex * Data = gsl_vector_complex_alloc( N );
    gsl_complex temp = gsl_complex_rect( 1, 2 );

    gsl_vector_complex_set_all( Data, temp );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++ ) {
        cout
            << GSL_REAL( gsl_vector_complex_get( Data, i ) )
            << " "
            << GSL_IMAG( gsl_vector_complex_get( Data, i ) )
            << endl;
    }

    gsl_vector_complex_free( Data );
}
```

My result is

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
```

as anyone would expect.

Unrelated remark aside: In terms of coding style, you might want to use `size_t` in place of `int` for `N` and `i` if you are using a recent version of GSL.

Comment: I indeed had a lot of problems during compilation so you must be right.